# Multiple JAX-RS applications in the same WAR

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have

```
@ApplicationPath("/resourcesP")
public class RestfulPrediction extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        set.add(PredictionsRS.class);
        return set;
    }
}
```

And

```
@ApplicationPath("/resourcesA")
public class RestfulAdage extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        set.add(Adages.class);
        return set;
    }
}
```

Two different ApplicationPath and the class are as follows.

```
@Path("/")
public class service.Adages {}

@Path("/")
public class webservices.PredictionsRS {}
```

Both of them are declared in different ApplicationPath. I'm using Jersey and the config in web.xml looks like

```
  <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            service
            webservices
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

And I'm getting

> SEVERE: Conflicting URI templates. The URI template / for root
>   resource class  service.Adages and the URI template / transform to the
>   same regular expression (/.*)?

Why if I have two different ApplicationPath this exception comes at startup ?

If I take out a package in param-value this works, also if I change one of the @Path annotations this works, so it is a problem with my configuration ?

I'm using Jersey 1.10. Thanks all.

Comment: Have you tried a different than `/` path (e.g `/another`) for both Rest Resources ?

Comment: Yes I tried and it is working if I have different paths in each  class pointed by the ApplicationPath, I think jersey is assuming that I want to use the same Path in the same ApplicationPath but this is not correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You did not define your JAX-RS applications in your `web.xml`. Try the following:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>full.name.RestfulAdage</servlet-name>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>full.name.RestfulPrediction</servlet-name>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>full.name.RestfulPrediction</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resourcesP/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>full.name.RestfulPrediction</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resourcesA/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and remove the `@ApplicationPAth` annotations from code.

I checked the above code with Jersey 2.7, servlet container 3.0 and it works. If still having that bug, try upgrading to Jersey 1.17 (which should not change any behavior from Jersey 1.10, and fix bugs instead) and eventually using also a servlet container 3.0.

**UPDATE**

After checking the possibilities the configuration below work with Jersey 1.17

```xml
   <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.koitoer.webservices
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

It seems there is bug in the spec in older version of Jersey that kind of circle back the references and mark as duplicate endpoints. Using the configuration above both endpoints load without any problem.

> 8/04/2014 09:13:40 PM
> com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer
> addServletWithApplication INFO: Registering the Jersey servlet
> application, named com.koitoer.webservices.chapter2.service2.RestfulPrediction, at the
> servlet mapping, **/resourcesP/***, with the Application class of the same
> name

> 8/04/2014 09:13:40 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer
> addServletWithApplication INFO: Registering the Jersey servlet
> application, named com.koitoer.webservices.chapter2.RestfulAdage, at
> the servlet mapping, **/resourcesA/***, with the Application class of the
> same name

Comment: Hi @AndreiI for the response, so according to this I need to create a servlet for each ApplicationPath I have in the application, as your comment below I suppose this MUST to be supported but it is not? My understanding here is my config is correct just the jersey is not playing well with it

Comment: I have never tried the code above, neither to deploy multiple applications in the same WAR. In RestEasy 2.3.0 (!not Jersey, what you use!) that is not supported, although it should be. I propose you to try the code above, and if that does not work, try using [servlet filters](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.2), instead of servlet definitions

Comment: Hi AndreI thanks for the highlights here, actually I was working with old version of jersey I am following a tutorial, probably so old XD. Based on that I dont want to change the dependencies, I look into the documentation and it seems your configuration is correct although I was thinking servlet-class is missing but after checking is not. For now I'm able to solve the issue. I just want to make an update in your response and mark as the correct one , thanks for all.

Answer (score -1):

You should have a single subclass of `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` in your webapp, and then use different `@Path` annotation values on your `service.Adages` and `webservices.PredictionsRS` resource types. 
AFAIK, in JEE6 containers, you are not allowed to have 2 such subclasses...

Comment: That is not true, check for example this BUG in RestEASY (the guys thought the same, but the spec does not forbid that): https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-650 Now I am saying it MUST be supported, and not that IT IS supported.

Comment: @andrei thanks for pointing this, I did not know about that. I assumed that not more than 1 application was allowed in a webapp, but actually, the spec does not explicitly forbid more than one application.

Comment: Hi Xavier I think this is allowed probably not in the way that I'm using but it seems create different servlet in the same web app is working