# find path to JAX-RS resource

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, ear

I just can't find out the path to access my JAX-RS resource which is deployed to wildfly.

ear.ear pom:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>jee-services</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.mycompany</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<packaging>ear</packaging>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>ear</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb_book</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

ejb_book pom:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>jee-services</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.mycompany</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>
<artifactId>ejb_book</artifactId>
```

application config

```
@ApplicationPath("/resources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
}
```

resource

```
@Stateless
@Path("/books")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class BookResource extends AbstractFacade<Book> {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @GET
    @Path("/getBooks")
    public Book getBook() {
        return new Book();
    }
```

I think the issue is that I'm packaging my ejb_book.jar into ear.ear (where I collect all other ejb-modules)

I tried:

```
localhost:8080/ear/resources/books/getBooks
```

and many other combinations but none of them worked.

The application deploys fine to the WildFly server.

BTW: is there a tool to help people access their JAX-RS resource? From the IDE for example. So my question wouldn't be a problem anymore.

Comment: Are you packaging also a WAR within your EAR? You need to provide a context-root in order to be able to access your REST service.

Comment: No there is no WAR. I just call the url in my browser. Do I miss something?

Comment: Yes, you've missed. As mentioned in the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1459700634_e34cc8220f019bf96f82813e0e098184) "*A JAX-RS application is packaged as a Web application in a .war file.*". Therefore, you need to have a WAR in order to provide a *context-root* to your application's REST service. Only then you'll be able to call your REST service in the form: *http://localhost:8080/context-root/ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/resources/books/getBooks*.

Comment: Thanks so far! So i could just add an empty WAR and add it to my ear as another module? Or whats the best practice here when deploying a backend like this?

Comment: Well, firstly you should justify (to yourself) the need of having an EAR as opposition to just pack everything in a WAR and place your dependencies in your WAR's WEB-INF/lib. Because, after all, you're trying to provide a REST API. On the other hand, if you're trying to provide more APIs than your REST one, then yes, you could have an EAR with two modules: your WAR and your EJB.

Comment: Ok I replaced the EAR with a WAR file. I added WEB-INF with web.xml. The module-dependencies are the same (in pom.xml). Is that right or what else do I need to change? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108099/discussion-between-aribeiro-and-codefella).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the JAX-RS 2.0 specification, section **2.3.2 Servlet**

> *A JAX-RS application is packaged as a Web application in a .war file.*

Since you're not packaging your application as a WAR module and neither you have a WAR module in your EAR, you're not providing a context-root to your (web) application.

This is preventing you from accessing your REST API through the desired way:

```
http://localhost:8080/<context-root>/resources/books/getBooks
```

As a solution, you could either package your entire application as a WAR, placing the application classes in WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib and required libraries in WEB-INF/lib, or you could maintain the use your EAR, adding to it a WAR module.

Comment: whats the state of the art project structure of a JavaEE app? Lets say its only backend and exposes some rest resources. like i did. Separted WARs for each domain (microservices) or everything in one WAR ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understood your question but as far as the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html#new-webapp) goes, everything will be placed in a single WAR. Now, when you say *Separted WARs for each domain* you mean you have several JAX-RS applications and each one of them will be in a WAR?

Comment: Yes. I mean if it comes to big applications you have to structure them somehow. Then creating a user.war which is responsible for all the business logic in this domain. And then a product.war and so on. Or whats the way to go for concern separation?

Comment: I don't think that one should create a WAR per functionality if that's what you mean. You'd create a WAR for your web application and then you could have a JAR, for instance, per service. Then, in your WAR's *web.xml* file, you'd have to define each JAX-RS service as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22931203/1346996). Then, it's up to whoever is developing, to define the architecture in accordance to his/her needs.